# Visual Studio 2010 installation path

Tags: visual-studio-2010, installation, registry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [programmatically retrieve Visual Studio install directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504/programmatically-retrieve-visual-studio-install-directory)

I want to get the path of my Visual Studio 2010 installation. I tried to get it from the Windows registry. It works perfectly for specific SKU. For example, Ultimate version of VS2010 uses`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\Setup\VS` key to store the installation path. But the Express version has a different path in the registry.

How I can determine the VS2010 installation path exactly without knowing the SKU?

Answer (score 0):

I think your only option is to probe the different locations one by one. Note that only Express and non-Express are actually in different locations as far as I know (that is, there's no difference between Professional, Ultimate, etc)

Comment: I'm not sure that difference for Express only. Can you share link about it? I can't find it.