# DLL exporting issue between a Visual Studios Enterprise and Professional Edition

Tags: c#, app-config

My friend has a project that was built using **Visual Studios Enterprise Edition** and my project has the Professional Edition.

When my friend tries to build his .dll files it shows an error saying that it cant build due to a path error. It can't find the Enterprise folder in the destination file.

Is there a **.config** file where I can say

```
#if VISUAL_STUDIO_ENTERPRISE
   //TODO: path\to\enterprise\folder\...
#else if VISUAL_STUDIO_PROFESSIONAL
   //TODO: path\to\professional\folder\...
#endif
```

Comment: The actual flavor of Visual Studio shouldn't matter at all for something like this.  Are you trying to *write* to Visual Studio's program directory?  If so, you should seriously consider not doing that.

Comment: @BradleyUffner No, what I'm trying to do is calling a file that is located in Microsoft Visual Studios\2017 but its trying to find the Enterprise folder whereas I only have the Professional folder

Comment: You might have better luck querying the registry for the installation directory of Visual Studio. Here is [some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504/programmatically-retrieve-visual-studio-install-directory) showing how to do that.  You may have to update the keys slightly, as they look like they are for older versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: Ahh, I just noticed that your error is happening at build time, so getting the path from the registry won't work.  Your best bet is to copy the .dll in to a path that is local to your project, usually a "lib" folder it created as a sibling to the .proj file.  Then reference the .dll from *that* folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you specify the location of the file in the Visual Studio directory using an environment variable?

Looking at my system, at a VS 2017 command prompt, I have an environment variable `VSINSTALLDIR` which points to my installation location, including the edition. As an example, my value points to:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\